# Dot operator in haskell with multi-parameter functions

Tags: haskell, pointfree, dot-operator

I want to write a function point-free in haskell, to keep things simple lets say I want to make this function:

```
maxmin :: Ord a => a -> a -> a -> a
maxmin a b c = max a (min b c)
```

I can improve this to

```
maxmin a b = (max a) . (min b)
```

but is there any way to get rid of a and b?

Comment: Point-free is a code *style*, and as such should only be used when it improves readability; the cases where point-free notation compiles differently (because of inlining) are not something you have to worry about in general (think about that after profiling). In your case, I'd say point-free doesn't help; renaming `maxmin` to `constrainTo` would be a much more expressive change, for example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wouldn't say this is simplier but here you go:

```
maxmin :: Ord a => a -> a -> a -> a                                             
maxmin = (. min) . (.) . max
```

(Generated with `pl` tool from `lambdabot` http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree)

```
lambdabot> pl maxmin a b c = max a (min b c)
maxmin = (. min) . (.) . max
```

Answer (score 4):

You just use the ["three laws of sections"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13147064/849891) for that,

```
(a `op` b) = (a `op`) b = (`op` b) a = op a b
```

so that

```
import Control.Arrow

maxmin a b = (max a) . (min b)
           = (.) (max a) (min b)
           = uncurry (.) (max a, min b)
           = uncurry (.) . (max *** min) $ (a, b)
           = curry (uncurry (.) . (max *** min)) a b
```

which is not too readable either. :)