# Rewrite recursion function as a pipeline functions composition

Tags: haskell, recursion, pointfree, pipelined-function

I'm writing my homework (CIS194 Haskell course).

I must rewrite the following recursive function to pipeline functions (without obvious recursion).

```
fun2 :: Integer -> Integer
fun2 1 = 0
fun2 n 
    | even n = n + fun2 ( n ‘div‘ 2 )
    | otherwise = fun2 (3 * n + 1)
```

My first try is here:

```
fun2''' = sum 
          . (filter (even)) 
          . unfoldr (\x -> if (even x) 
                          then Just (x, x `div` 2)
                          else if (x==1) then Nothing 
                               else Just (x, x * 3 + 1))
```

Is this a normal solution or is it weird?

And how can I rewrite `fun2` better?

Now i try write version with `takeWhile` and `iterate`

my 2nd try:

```
fun2'' :: Integer -> Integer
fun2'' = sum 
         . (filter even) 
         . takeWhile (/=1) 
         . iterate (\x -> if even x 
                          then x `div` 2
                          else x * 3 + 1 )
```

i have little problems with `until` version now.

Comment: A few unnecessary parentheses, but it's rather good. I'm optimisitc that your `takeWhile` + `iterate` approach will turn out well too.

Comment: Also instead of returning `x` for the case when it's odd, you could return `Just (0, x * 3 + 1)` and avoid `filter`ing later.

Comment: What about applying Collatz conjecture  and writing as fun2 _ = 0

Comment: @LukaRahne it is not 0. The function sums up all evens in a Collatz sequence for a given number. The conjecture states it's finite, and to be so it must end with a sequence of powers of 2, i.e. evens (up to the finishing 1).

Answer (score 2):

Looks not bad, the only thing here that's a bit of a red flag in Haskell is `else if`. In this case, it can be rewritten nicely in applicative style:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections     #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad (guard)

fun2''' = sum 
          . filter even
          . unfoldr ( \x -> fmap (x,) $
                   x`div`2 <$ guard(even x)
               <|> x*3 + 1 <$ guard( x/=1 )
             )
```

Comment: You can read a chain of `a<$guard α <|> b<$guard β <|> ...` much like what you'd write in a procedural language as `if α then return a; if β then return b...`. — It works like this: `guard ψ` is `Just ()` if _ψ_ is true, and `Nothing` if it's false. `<$` replaces the `()` with the value to its left, or leaves the `Nothing` as it is. `<|>` finally picks the first `Just a` it finds, skipping any `Nothing`s.

Comment: @groovy: `a <$ b` is just `const a <$> b` or `fmap (const a) b`. Think about it as a special version of `<$>` that ignores the values on the right--that's why the symbol is just like `<$>` without the right `>`.

Comment: this code [fails with a type mismatch error on Ideone](http://ideone.com/MNyLKN). [Sticking some `runKleisli` and `Kleisli` in there](http://ideone.com/eScxaq) did the trick. But that's hardly an intuitive or easy-to-read code (for me at least). :) Is there an easier way to mend this code?

Comment: @WillNess: right, that Arrow thing was a bit too much, and with the required kleisli wrapper really not nice anymore. I went back to the [plain applicative version](http://ideone.com/2bi6nK).

Comment: thanks! (I could've looked into the edit history, it turns out...)

Answer (score 1):

Nested `if`s can now be written with [multi-way IF](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6-latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#multi-way-if):

```
g :: Integer -> Integer
g = sum . 
     unfoldr (\x-> 
          if | even x    -> Just (x, x `div` 2) 
             | x==1      -> Nothing 
             | otherwise -> Just (0, x * 3 + 1))
```

Or you can define your own *if* operator,

```
(??) t (c,a) | t = c | otherwise = a

g = sum . unfoldr (\x-> even x ?? (Just (x, x `div` 2) ,
                        (x==1) ??  (Nothing, Just (0, x * 3 + 1))))
```

Same function with `until`, with `sum` and `filter` fused into it:

```
g = fst . until ((==1).snd) 
            (\(s,n) -> if even n then (s+n,n`div`2) else (s,3*n+1)) 
    . ((,)0)
```

or

```
g = sum . filter even . f

f :: Integer -> [Integer]
f = (1:) . fst . until ((==1).snd) 
            (\(s,n) -> if even n then (n:s,n`div`2) else (n:s,3*n+1)) 
    . ((,)[])
```

The last function, `f`, shows the whole Collatz sequence for a given input number, reversed.

Comment: Please, describe (1:) ,  ((,)0)  ,  ((,)[]) sentences. I never meet it before.

Comment: @СергейКузминский That's "operator sections", i.e. partially applied operators. `(1:) == (:) 1 == (\y -> 1:y)`. `(,)x == (x ,) == (\y -> (x, y))`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/13477198/849891 .

Comment: @СергейКузминский congrats on reaching the 15 rep! :) You have the power to up-vote now. ;) ;) (and you always had the power to *accept* an answer).