# How to read the following haskell definition " Num (a -> b) => [a] -> [b] "

Tags: haskell, types

I am trying to understand below type

```
Prelude> :t map(10$)
map(10$) :: Num (a -> b) => [a] -> [b]
```

Comment: What do you understand about it? What do you have trouble understanding?

Comment: Having trouble understanding what Num(a-> b) means in this context ? Num instance for a function type ? I recently started learning haskell ,so far i have seen Num a type but not Num (function).

Comment: `(10 $)` is a function, `(10 $) x = 10 $ x = 10 x`. This demands `10` to be of type `a -> b`, because general function application is `(f :: a -> b) (x :: a) :: b`.

In Haskell, numeric literals have type `Num a => a`, meaning, *any* type `a` which is **in** the type class `Num`.

Thus the type of `(10 $)` must be `(Num a) => (a -> b)`. Indeed this is not a common situation. You probably didn't mean for `10` to serve as a function.

Comment: You are right @WillNess, I dint mean 10 to serve as a function am just trying to understand how map function and dollar operator work in different combinations. Thanks

Comment: @WillNess , What happens if I put 10 on right hand side of $ like `($10) x`,how x is applied to 10 ? (for example x = (\y->y+1)) .Thanks

Comment: @anired: try it and see!  If you're still confused, try asking another question here.

Comment: @jcast I tried it `Prelude>  ($10) (\x->x+3)` returns `13`  , here I want to know how the literal  `10 ` is applied to function ,as `($(\x->x+3)) 10` fails.

Comment: @anired In one case, `10` is the second argument to `($)`; in the other, it is the first, Now, take a second look at the type of `($)`.

Comment: @duplode I tried a lot to find documentation about ($) but no luck , would really appreciate if you can point me to one. Thanks much

Comment: `($10) (\x -> x+3)` is equivalent to `(\f -> f $ 10)(\x->x+3)`, which reduces to `(\x -> x + 3) $ 10`, and finally to `10 + 3` and `13`. `($)` is just function application in operator form: `f $ x = f x`. It might make more sense if you give it a different name and put it in normal prefix form: `apply f x = f x`.

Comment: @anired Try `:t ($)`. [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%24) can also help in such cases.

Answer (score 4):

*How to understand a constraint like `Num (a->b)`?* can be answered more generally: how to understand `Num SomeCompoundType`?

Quite simple, such a constraint means that you tried to treat a type as a number type though it is not a number type. Such a type is just bogus, though it is not a type error (and theoretically, somebody *could* add a `Num (a -> b)` instance).

With `Num` in particular, “treated as a number” usually just means that you wrote a number literal in a place where e.g. a function is expected. The section `(10$)` wants `10` to be a function. Because Haskell number literals are polymorphic, there is per se nothing wrong with that: `10` *could* be a function if only it had the suitable `instance Num (a -> b)`. Just, this instance does not exist, but because somebody could in principle yet add it later, the compiler leaves this as a constraint-to-be-fulfilled.

Answer (score 3):

`(10 $)` is a function, `(10 $) x = 10 $ x = 10 x`. This demands `10` to be of type `a -> b`, because general function application is `(f :: a -> b) (x :: a) :: b`.

In Haskell, numeric literals have type `Num a => a`, meaning, *any* type `a` which is **in** the type class `Num`.

Thus the type of `(10 $)` must be `(Num a) => (a -> b)`. Indeed this is not a common situation. You probably didn't mean for `10` to serve as a function.

On the other hand, `($ 10) x = x $ 10 = x 10`. This is known as "operator sections": [`` (a `op` b) = (a `op`) b = (`op` b) a = op a b ``](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13477198/849891). When special characters (`$`, `:`, etc.) are used as "op" (operator), there's no need to put them inside the back-quotes.