# Giving too many arguments to a function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, I can give too few arguments to a function to get back a curried function:

```
-- the addition function
Prelude> :t (+) 
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a

-- curried with its first argument => the increment function
Prelude> :t (+) 1
(+) 1 :: Num a => a -> a

-- supplied with both arguments => the result
Prelude> :t (+) 1 2
(+) 1 2 :: Num a => a
```

But what do I get when I supply too many arguments?

```
Prelude> :t (+) 1 2 3
(+) 1 2 3 :: (Num a, Num (a -> t)) => t
```

What is this, does it have a name, and is it useful for anything?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40592338/how-to-read-the-following-haskell-definition-num-a-b-a-b

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read the following haskell definition " Num (a -> b) => \[a\] -> \[b\] "](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40592338/how-to-read-the-following-haskell-definition-num-a-b-a-b)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's useful to think about it this way. You *always* give exactly one argument to a function. `f a b` is exactly equivalent to `(f a) b`.

So `(+) 1 2 3` is the same as

```
 (((+) 1) 2) 3
```

Now we know what `((+) 1) 2` is, it's the same as `(+) 1 2` or `1 + 2` which is just 3. So the expression boils down to `3 3`.

How come it's not an error?

Integer literals in Haskell are overloaded. `3` could be of *any* type, provided this type has a `Num` instance. There is nothing illegal to give a `Num` instance to a function type either. The type inferencer tells you just that:

```
(Num a, Num (a -> t)) => t
```

This can be read as

> For any type `a` which has a `Num` instance, and any type `a->t` which also has a `Num` instance, the expression in question has type `t`.

Of course in practice such instances are unlikely, but one *can* in principle define them, and make the expression `(+) 1 2 3` evaluate to a well-defined value.

Comment: I see. So someone could  theoretically make an instance of `Num (a -> t)` for `Num a`, and then you'd want `(+) x y z` to check out for values of this type.

Comment: Could that theoretically be made to work even for literals? Is there a way to augment the interpretation of numeric literals in such a way that `1` can become  a function value (or anything else other than the conversions your compiler has built-in)?

Comment: Yes, having an instance of Num implies that you can use integer literals for your type. This is handled by `fromInteger` method. So `3` is really a `fromInteger (3::Integer)`. You get to write `fromInteger` for your instance so you can have 3 mean whatever (for examlple `const 3`).

Answer (score 5):

In general, you just get an error, because the result of applying a function to "enough" arguments does not produce a value that can be applied to another value as a function.

```
> (++) [1] [2] [3]

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Integer] -> t’
                  with actual type ‘[Integer]’
    • The function ‘(++)’ is applied to three arguments,
      but its type ‘[Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]’ has only two
      In the expression: (++) [1] [2] [3]
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = (++) [1] [2] [3]
    • Relevant bindings include it :: t (bound at <interactive>:1:1)
```

In the case of `(+)`, though, the return value can be of *any* type that has an instance of `Num`. Since `(+) 1 2` has type `Num a => a`, then if `a -> t` also had an instance of `Num`, it would be fine to assume that `(+) 1 2` could be applied again to a third value. This is a demonstration that type classes are *open*.

Comment: So I ran into this because the numeric literals are still "flexible" and could be interpreted as different instances of `Num`, and as far as the type-checker is concerned `1` could end up not just as an `Int` or `Fractional`, but also as an `a -> t` ?

Comment: I tried to force the arguments to be `Int` rather than `Num a`, and then it did immediately produce an error: `let one = 1 :: Int
:t (+) one one one   --> type error`