# Converting expression to pointfree style (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pointfree

I wrote this code and I have to rewrite it to the pointfree style:

```
num_of_occ ele list = length(filter(==ele)list)
```

So I did this:

```
num_of_occ ele = length . filter((==)ele)
```

It works. Than I did this:

```
num_of_occ = length . filter . (==)
```

And it doesnt... what's wrong with my line of thought?

Comment: see also ["three laws of sections"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139969/currying-3-arguments-in-haskell/13147064#13147064) .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a common error.  Here is the fix:

```
num_of_occ = (length .) . filter . (==)
```

It has to do with the number of arguments your function takes.  The function composition `(.)` operator works on functions with one argument, you need to apply it twice `(f .) .` to make it work on functions with two arguments.

There's actually a program on Hackage that will automatically convert a snippet of code to points free style, if you want to play with it.

```
$ cabal install pointfree
$ pointfree 'num_of_occ ele list = length (filter (== ele) list)'
num_of_occ = (length .) . filter . (==)
```

As noted, this needs a type signature to work correctly.  The reasons for this are relatively mundane but obscure, and the restriction exists to improve Haskell performance.  You can turn on the `NoMonomorphismRestriction` extension, or add a type signature:

```
num_of_occ :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
num_of_occ = (length .) . filter . (==)
```

Comment: Hmm... this one returns an error too. `a.hs:1:31:
    No instance for (Eq a0) arising from a use of `=='`

Comment: I'm testing on GHCI, version 7.6.1.

Comment: That's the [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction). Add a type signature or use `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction`.

Comment: fixed the typo `Eq a ->`. It should be `Eq a =>`.