# Please explain (forM_ [stdout, stderr] . flip hPutStrLn) :: String -> IO ()

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I'm having trouble understanding how this Haskell expression works:

```
import Control.Monad
import System.IO
(forM_ [stdout, stderr] . flip hPutStrLn) "hello world"
```

What is the `. flip hPutStrLn` part doing exactly? The type signatures seem complicated:

```
ghci> :type flip
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
ghci> :type (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
ghci> :type (. flip)
(. flip) :: ((b -> a -> c1) -> c) -> (a -> b -> c1) -> c
ghci> :type (. flip hPutStrLn)
(. flip hPutStrLn) :: ((Handle -> IO ()) -> c) -> String -> c
```

What becomes the left and right operands of the `(.)` operator as the expression is evaluated?

Another way to putting my question is, how does the left part of the expression at the top end up with a type signature like this:

```
(forM_ [stdout, stderr] . flip hPutStrLn) :: String -> IO ()
```

Comment: does comparing `:type (. hPutStrLn)` with `:type (. flip hPutStrLn)` help at all?

Comment: Who would write such code? The point-free style is really pointless here and hurts readability, IMHO

Comment: @NiklasB. it's not too bad to me, though I remember a time in the past when it would have been totally opaque.  It depends on your familiarity with the style, I think (or rather, obviously).

Comment: this might have been more readable ``forM_ [stdout, stderr] (`hPutStrLn`  "hello world")``, but YMMV. See also [three "laws" of operator sections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139969/currying-3-arguments-in-haskell/13147064#13147064).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The left and right operands of `(.)` are

```
forM_ [stdout, stderr]
```

and

```
flip hPutStrLn
```

respectively.

The type of [`hPutStrLn`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/System-IO.html#v:hPutStrLn) is

```
hPutStrLn :: Handle -> String -> IO ()
```

so `flip hPutStrLn` has type

```
flip hPutStrLn :: String -> Handle -> IO ()
```

As the type system tells you, `flip` is a combinator that swaps the order of another function’s arguments. Specified in the abstract

```
flip       :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
flip f x y =  f y x
```

From `ghci` you already know that the type of `(. flip hPutStrLn)` is

```
ghci> :type (. flip hPutStrLn)
(. flip hPutStrLn) :: ((Handle -> IO ()) -> c) -> String -> c
```

Working from the other direction, the type of the left side is

```
ghci> :type forM_ [stdout, stderr]
forM_ [stdout, stderr] :: Monad m => (Handle -> m b) -> m ()
```

Observe how the types fit together.

```
(. flip hPutStrLn)     ::            ((Handle -> IO ()) -> c   ) -> String -> c
forM_ [stdout, stderr] :: Monad m =>  (Handle -> m  b ) -> m ()
```

Combining the two (calling the first with the second) gives

```
ghci> :type forM_ [stdout, stderr] . flip hPutStrLn
forM_ [stdout, stderr] . flip hPutStrLn :: String -> IO ()
```

In your question, the result of the composition is applied to a `String`, and that produces an I/O action that yields `()`, *i.e.*, we are mainly interested in its side effects of writing to the standard output and error streams.

With [point-free style](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree) such as the definition in your question, the programmer defines more complex functions in terms of smaller, simpler functions by composing them with `(.)`. The `flip` combinator is useful for reordering arguments so as to make repeated partial applications fit together.

Comment: Very lucid answer. Thank you.

Comment: @dan You’re welcome! Stick with it. The journey of learning Haskell is wonderful.

Answer (score 7):

`flip` reverses the arguments of an input function, i.e.:

```
flip hPutStrLn == \a b -> hPutStrLn b a
```

The `.` is a function composition operator (or infix function), which lets you nicely chain functions together. Without this operator your expression can be rewritten as follows:

```
forM_ [stdout, stderr] ((flip hPutStrLn) "hello world")
```

which is the same as:

```
forM_ [stdout, stderr] (flip hPutStrLn "hello world")
```

or, using the application operator:

```
forM_ [stdout, stderr] $ flip hPutStrLn "hello world"
```

---

Concerning the `.` operands question. Consider the type signature of `.`:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

You can view it as a function from 3 arguments: a function `b -> c`, a function `a -> b` and a value `a` - to a resulting value `c`, but also due to [Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), you can see it as a function from two arguments: `b -> c` and `a -> b` - to a result function of type `a -> c`. And this is what happens in your example: you pass two functions (`forM_ [stdout, stderr]` and `flip hPutStrLn`, which are themselves results of currying) to `.` and get a function of type `String -> IO ()` as a result.

Comment: Which is the same as `forM_ [stdout, stderr] (\h -> hPutStrLn h "hello world")`

Comment: What are the left and right operands of the (.) function in the above example?

Comment: OK I think I get it, but this confused me because what is being composed is `String -> Handle -> IO ()` and `(Handle -> IO b) -> IO ()`. The trick seems to be seeing `Handle -> IO ()` as a unit.

Comment: Plus I've never seen `forM_ [x, y]` by itself on the left side of a (.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a somewhat shorter derivation of that type (as hinted in the 2nd part of Nikita Volkov's answer).

Knowing `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` and `(f . g) x = f (g x)`, so that

```
(f . g) :: a -> c      where  g :: (a -> b)  and  f :: (b -> c)
```

(the `b` in `a -> b` and `b -> c` disappears after performing [the unification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_%28computer_science%29), giving the `a -> c` type) and since

```
flip hPutStrLn         ::    String -> (Handle -> IO ())             -- g
forM_ [stdout, stderr] :: (Monad m) => (Handle -> m  b ) -> m ()     -- f
```

<sub>(we put parentheses around the `Handle -> IO ()` in the first type, using the fact that in types `->` is right associative),</sub> the resulting type of *composing* the second with the first (via the [*function composition*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) operator) is

```
(Monad m) => String -> m ()     where  m ~ IO  and b ~ ()
                                (found by unification of
                                        Handle -> IO ()  and
                                        Handle -> m  b       )
```

i.e. `String -> IO ()`.

The order of arguments for `(.)` takes a little getting used to; it fires up its second argument function first, and then uses the result to call its first argument function. If we import `Control.Arrow` we can then use `>>>` operator which is like `(.)` in reverse, with functions: `(f . g) x == (g >>> f) x`.