# Need help understanding (\x -> ) in Haskell

Tags: haskell

On ZVON, one of the definitions provided for the takeWhile function is

```
Input: takeWhile (\x -> 6*x < 100) [1..20]

Output: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
```

Can someone explain what the portion `(\x -> 6*x < 100)` means?

Comment: It says in "Learn you a Haskell" (or in the docs?) that \ is supposed to look like the lambda greek letter: λ. [Here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Anonymous_function) are Haskell's docs on anonymous functions

Comment: Mariano, why didn't you post your answer as an answer?

Comment: `(\x -> 6*x < 100)` is the same as `((<100).(6*))`.

Comment: What does that `.` mean?

Comment: `(.) f g x = (f .) g x = (. g) f x = (f . g) x = f (g x)`. So `((<100).(6*)) x = (<100) ( (6*) x) = (<100) (6*x) = (6*x)<100`. IOW, `((<100).(6*)) = \x -> (6*x)<100`. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139969/currying-3-arguments-in-haskell/13147064#13147064

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's an anonymous function definition, otherwise known as a lambda-expression.  `(\x -> 6*x < 100)` is a function which takes a number, and returns the boolean result of the inequality.

Since functional languages like Haskell frequently take functions as arguments, it is convenient to be able to define simple functions in-line, without needing to assign them a name.

Answer (score 8):

Originally, the story goes, [Alonzo Church](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alonzo_Church) wanted to mark variables in functional expressions with a [circumflex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumflex), like e.g. `(ŷ.x(yz))` but the Princeton printing press just couldn't do that at the time. He then wanted at least to print [carets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret) before the vars, like this: `(^y.x(yz))`, but they couldn't do that either.

The next best option was to use the Greek letter *lambda* instead, and so they ended up writing `(λy.x(yz))` etc., hence the "lambda" in *lambda-expression*. It was all just a typographical accident.

Today on ASCII terminals we can't even use the letter `λ`, and so in Haskell we use a backslash instead (and an arrow in place of a dot in original [lambda-expressions notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus)):

```
(\y -> x (y z))
```

stands for a function `g` such that

```
g y = x (y z)
```

---

Source: read it somewhere, don't remember where.

Answer (score 4):

`(\x -> 6*x < 100)` is a *lambda*, an anonymous function that takes one argument (here called `x`) and computes & returns `6*x < 100`, i.e., tests whether that number multiplied by 6 is less than 100.

Answer (score 4):

It is a lambda function, that is, a function that you define in the spot mostly for convenience. You read it as "take x as your input, multiply it by 6 and see if it is less than 100". There are some other amenities related, though. For example, in Haskell Lambda functions and ordinary functions have a lexical environment associated and are properly speaking [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29), so that they can perform computations using the environment as input.

Comment: It might help if we mention that if this were a named (top level) function it could look like `someFunctionName x = 6*x < 100`.