# Haskell - Capitalize all letters in a list [String] with toUpper

Tags: list, haskell, dictionary, filter, toupper

I have a list [String] the task ist to remove those elements in the list, which have "q" or "p" and then capitalize all letters in the list with toUpper.

What I tried yet is as follow:

```
delAndUpper :: [String] -> [String]
delAndUpper myList = filter (\x -> not('p' `elem` x || 'q' `elem` x)) myList
```

It removes the unwanted elements from the list properly, however I can't apply toUpper on this list since the type of toUpper is Char.

I tried it with map and it does not work.

```
delAndUpper myList = map toUpper (filter (\x -> not('p' `elem` x || 'q' `elem` x)) myList)
```

I know, that toUpper in this line of code gets a list as value and therefore it can't work, but know how to go a level down into the list and the apply map toUpper.

Could you please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Greetings

Answer (score 9):

### Mapping one level deeper

You need to use `map (map toUpper)`.

This is because you have `[String]` instead of `String`.

```
toUpper           :: Char -> Char
map toUpper       :: [Char] -> [Char]
```

i.e.

```
map toUpper       :: String -> String
map (map toUpper) :: [String] -> [String]
```

`map toUpper` capitalises a String, by making each letter uppercase, so `map (map toUpper)` capitalises each String in a list of Strings.

Your function becomes

```
delAndUpper myList = map (map toUpper) (filter (\x -> not('p' `elem` x || 'q' `elem` x)) myList)
```

dave4420 made a [good suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16404641/1598537) that `(map.map) toUpper` is a neat way of writing `map (map toUpper)` that helps you think two list levels in quite simply and naturally - have a look at his answer too.

### Can we un-hardwire the p and q?

You asked if there was a shorter way to write the condition, and didn't like hard coding the `` `q` `` and `` `p` ``. I agree those multiple `` `elem` `` bits aren't pretty. Let's pass in the list of disallowed letters and tidy up a bit:

```
delAndUpper omit strings = map (map toUpper) (filter ok strings) where
            ok xs = not (any (`elem` omit) xs)
```

Here `` (`elem` omit) `` checks a character if it's in the list of ones that would cause us to omit the word, so `` (any (`elem` omit) xs) `` checks if any of the characters of `xs` are forbidden. Of course if none are forbidden, it's `ok`.

Your original `delAndUpper` would now be `delAndUpper "pq"`, or if you also want to disallow capital P and Q, `delAndUpper "pqPQ"`. (More on this later.)

### Can we make it more concise?

Let's see if we can't write `ok` a little shorter. My first thought was to use `pointfree` on it (see [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13140051/1598537) for details of how to get it running in ghci), but it seemed to hang, so using some standard transformation tricks, we can compose `not` with a function that takes two arguments before giving us a Bool by doing `(not.).f` instead of `not.f` as we would with a function which just gave us a Bool after the first input. `any` is taking `` (`elem` omit) `` as its first argument. This gives us

```
ok xs = ((not.).any) (`elem` omit) xs
```

from which we can remove the trailing xs:

```
ok = ((not.).any) (`elem` omit)
```

and inline:

```
delAndUpper omit strings = map (map toUpper) (filter (((not.).any) (`elem` omit)) strings)
```

I'm not keen on the trailing `strings` either:

```
delAndUpper omit = map (map toUpper).filter (((not.).any) (`elem` omit))
```

(We could get rid of the `omit` argument as well and go completely point free, but that would go quite a bit too far down the hard-to-read road for my taste.)

### Whither Q?

```
> delAndUpper "pq" $ words "The Queen has probably never had a parking ticket."
["THE","QUEEN","HAS","NEVER","HAD","A","TICKET."]
```

Is this the required behaviour? It seems strange to carefully exclude the lowercase variants and then make everything uppercase. We could do it the other way round:

```
upperAndDel omit = filter (((not.).any) (`elem` omit)).map (map toUpper)
```

giving

```
> upperAndDel "PQ" $ words "The Queen has probably never had a parking ticket."
["THE","HAS","NEVER","HAD","A","TICKET."]
```

Comment: Hello all, **thank you very much indeed** for so much help! I had tried every thing for about 1 hour. On of my solutions/attempts was map map but I sat the brace wrong like this: `delAndUpper myList = map (map toUpper (filter (\x -> not('p' `elem` x || 'q' `elem` x)) myList))`. and I thought it's the wrong path :-(

Comment: is it possible to rewrite this conditional statement in a more compact manner like list or so ´'p' `elem` x || 'q' `elem` x´. e.g if there are not two characters as condition but three and four and so on, imho it would be better, if one could have them as a concatanation and pass it as a parameter to the function instead of hard coding it. Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> I know, that toUpper in this line of code gets a list as value and therefore it can't work, but know how to go a level down into the list and the apply map toUpper.

Use `(map . map)` instead of `map`.

n.b. `(map . map) toUpper` is the same as `map (map toUpper)` as suggested by the other answers. I mention it because, personally, I find it clearer: it looks more like it is going down two levels to apply `toUpper`. (You may not be familiar with the function composition operator `(.)`, look it up or ask about it if you need to.)

Other functions with a similar type (`(a -> b) -> something a -> something b`), such as `fmap`, `Data.Map.map`, `first` and `second`, can be combined with each other and with `map` in a similar way.

Perhaps you don't find `(map . map) toUpper` clearer than `map (map toUpper)`; fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, you just need a second `map`.

```
map (map toUpper) (filter (\x -> not('p' `elem` x || 'q' `elem` x)) myList)
```

This is because `String` is completely synonymous with `[Char]` in vanilla haskell. Since the type of map is

```
(a->b) -> [a] -> b
```

and we have

```
toUpper :: Char -> Char
String  :: [Char]
```

We'll get back another `String`, except capitalized.

By the way, that ugly-ish filter can be replaced made prettier with by making it use arrows :) (Think of these like more structured functions)

```
map (map toUpper) . filter $ elem 'p' &&& elem 'q' >>> arr (not . uncurry (||))
```

Gratuitousness? Maybe, but kinda cool.