# Haskell filter function with multiple parameters

Tags: haskell, filter, parameters, predicate, partial-application

I'm trying to learn Haskell and wondered how to filter a given list, with a function that takes multiple parameters, passing each element of the list with other unchanging elements to the function, to create a new list.

I understand that I can do this to use a bool function to filter the list:

```
newList = filter theFunction aList
```

but what happens when the theFunction takes other parameters like this:

```
theFunction -> elementOfAList -> Int -> Bool
```

how then could I filter each element of the list, whilst parsing in another element to the function? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Edit -> To provide some more information, if I wanted to have a list of integers from [1..10], that get filtered through a function that takes two integers and returns true if the first one is smaller, how could I do that?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean, please add some code/pseudocode explaining _how you would like to use this_.

Comment: to your edit: the first part of my answer fully applies. that is, if you use the same int, like `theFunction x i = x < i` and then `filter (flip theFunction 5) aList`, keeping in the resulting list all elements of `aList` that are smaller than 5.

Comment: Seems like this is not a filtering but a folding job. You may try `(==) <$> foldr1 (\x y -> bool (minBound :: Int) x (x <= y)) <*> head`. Where `bool` is a ternary operator from `Data.Bool.bool` with type `a -> a -> Bool -> a`.

Comment: @Redu [consider](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Bool.html#v:bool) `[1,2,3,1]`: `3 <= 2` is false, so `minBound` will be produced - why?? --- besides, `foldr1`'s implementation (both [old](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#foldr1) and [new](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#line-205)) guarantees the reducing function to be called only with existing values. and [`minimum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:minimum) already exists.

Comment: @Will Ness I think unlike `reduceRight` in JS, in `\ x y ->`,  `x` is the previous element from left. That's why `[1,2,3,4 ]` just resolves `True`. Am i missing something..?

Comment: @Redu I'm sorry, I should've written `3 <= 1` is false. `foldr1 g [1,2,3,1] == g 1 (g 2 (g 3 1))`.

Comment: @Will Ness Honestly... my interpretation of the question was to check simply if the list is in ascending order. May be i am totally off.

Comment: @Redu yet for `[minBound, 3, 1]` your function will return ... `True`. --- I read the question as more about the general use patterns. --- `ascending = and . (zipWith (<=) <*> drop 1)`.

Comment: @Will Ness That's indeed true as an edge case. It's better be done by `foldr` and an initial like `(True, maxBound)`. That `zipWith (<=)` applicative version is beautiful.

Comment: @Redu any use of bounds like that is a code smell.

Comment: @Will Ness Totally agreed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you use a partially applied predicate function, like this

```
-- theFunction :: elementOfAList -> Int -> Bool       -- "::" means, "is of type"
newList = filter (flip theFunction i) aList
```

because

```
flip theFunction i x = theFunction x i
```

by the definition of `flip`, so `flip theFunction` has the type `Int -> elementOfAList -> Bool`:

```
flip ::       (a -> b   -> c   ) -> b -> a -> c
theFunction :: a -> Int -> Bool
flip theFunction ::               Int -> a -> Bool
flip theFunction  (i ::  Int)         :: a -> Bool
```

where `i` is some `Int` value defined elsewhere. `a` is a type variable, i.e. it can be any type, like the type of a list's elements (i.e. for a list `aList :: [a]` each element has the same type, `a`).

For example, with `theFunction x i = x < i` you could call `filter (flip theFunction 5) aList`, keeping in the resulting list all the elements of `aList` that are smaller than 5. Normally this would just be written as `filter (< 5) aList`, with [*operator sections*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13147064/849891) (of which `(< 5)` is one example, absolutely equivalent to the `flip theFunction 5`).

---

The above *filtering* will use the same `Int` value `i` in calling `theFunction` for every element `x` of a list `aList`. If you wanted to recalculate that `Int`, it is done with another pattern (i.e., higher-order function),

```
mapAccumL :: (acc -> x -> (acc, y)) -> acc -> [x] -> (acc, [y])
```

Suppose you wanted to keep in a list of ints all the elements as they are being found by `theFunction`. Then you could do it like

```
theFunction :: elementOfAList -> Int -> Bool
foo :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
foo i xs = concat (snd (mapAccumL g i xs))    -- normally written as
        -- concat $ snd $ mapAccumL g i xs     -- or 
        -- concat . snd $ mapAccumL g i xs      -- or even
        -- concat . snd . mapAccumL g i $ xs
  where
  g acc x   -- g :: (acc -> x -> (acc, y))  according to mapAccumL's signature
    | theFunction x acc = (x, [x])   -- include `x` in output, and update the acc
    | otherwise         = (acc, [])  -- keep the accumulated value, and skip this `x`
```

Because both `x` and `acc` are used in the same role (the first element of the tuple) they both must be of same type.

Comment: Perhaps it would be more effective, didactically, to use a lambda expression rather than `flip`.

Comment: @dfeuer I like combinatory definitions more. `\ ->` look like more heavy syntax to get lost in.

Comment: I like neither, I would write this as ``filter (`theFunction`i) aList``. (But preferrable would of course be if `theFunction` were defined in flipped form in the first place.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout me too (the ``(`op` v)`` stuff). I meant for the exposition, here, because both the other two options involve new *syntax* that needs to be explained to / processed by a learner. `theFunction` is presumably something that the OP *already* has, a.o.t. defining it especially for this use.

Comment: Good answer. Partial function application is a very powerful technique unfamiliar to many non-Haskell hackers and has a very sweet syntax in Haskell. My only additional suggestion is that if theFunction is really just as simple as suggested by the original post, it would be even clearer when not even given a name.  Just plain ‘filter (<x)’ (where x is the number cutoff number) will work with fewer keystrokes and greater readability.

Comment: @CarlEdman thank you. re: your suggestion, this *is* mentioned in the end of first part (just above the divider line).

Comment: The combinatorial approach is perfectly fine if you just want to make a very local change, like `flip`, or if you can use something that scales fairly well, like the applicative idiom. But if you need to shuffle more arguments, or duplicate in a more controlled way, you'll surely want lambdas at some point to prevent the code from turning into spaghetti. May I ask why you prefer to start teaching the combinatorial approach?

Comment: @dfeuer as I said in one of the above comments, it is immediately understandable without needing to know any additional syntax like that of lambdas or sections. So seems like a good fit for the first steps in learning Haskell. Of course what you said is absolutely valid and very soon lambda expressions are found out to be saving us creating a great number of unnecessary temporary functions just for shuffling some arguments. But also, a minimalist approach has its definite appeal, i.e., less distractions to overload the mind of a reader with.  As always, it's a balancing act.

Comment: @dfeuer overall, combinators are more on the pointfree side, and pointfree certainly is nice when appropriate. More algebraic code is easier to follow and reshuffle, a la Bird's program derivations.

Comment: @WillNess, can you point to a particular Bird reference I should see?

Comment: @dfeuer https://www.amazon.com/Pearls-Functional-Algorithm-Design-Richard/dp/0521513383/ref=asap_bc?ie=UTF8