# Understanding the signature of the function (.) (:)

Tags: haskell

could you explain how we go from :

```
Prelude Data.Monoid> :t (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
Prelude Data.Monoid> :t (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

to that :

```
Prelude Data.Monoid> :t (.)(:)
(.)(:) :: (a1 -> a2) -> a1 -> [a2] -> [a2]
```

More in general, I'm sometimes afraid of (.) like I don't feel it intuitively, if you have some tricks to share to better feel it, it's welcome :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's rename some things and put parenthesis:

```
(:) :: d -> ([d] -> [d])
```

Now, in the expresstion `(.) (:)` the `(:)` is the first argument of `(.)`. The first argument of `(.)` should have type `b -> c`. Thus,

```
b -> c = d -> ([d] -> [d])
```

which means

```
b = d
c = [d] -> [d]
```

The result of `(.) (:)` has type `(a -> b) -> a -> c`. Putting our `b` and `c` in, we get

```
(a -> d) -> a -> ([d] -> [d])
```

This is exactly what ghci told you, except for the type variables renamed as `a1 = a` and `a2 = d`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let us do the type inference. We thus have two function:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
(:) :: d -> [d] -> [d]
```

We here use `d` since the `a` in `(.)` is not *per se* the `a` in `(:)`, so we avoid confusion by using two separate type variables.

The type signatures in a more canonic form are:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> ((a -> b) -> (a -> c))
(:) :: d -> ([d] -> [d])
```

So now since `(:)` is the argument of a function application with `(.)` as function, we know that the type of `(:)` is the type of the *parameter* of `(.)`, so that means that `d -> ([d] -> [d]) ~ (b -> c)` (here the tilde `~` means that it is the same type). So therefore we know that:

```
  b -> c
~ d -> ([d] -> [d])
---------------------
b ~ d, c ~ [d] -> [d]
```

So that means that the `b` in the type signature of `(.)` is the same type as `d` in the type signature of `(:)`, and that `c ~ [d] -> [d]`.

So the as a result, we get:

```
  (.) (:) :: (a -> b) -> (a -> c))
= (.) (:) :: (a -> d) -> (a -> ([d] -> [d])))
= (.) (:) :: (a -> d) -> (a -> [d] -> [d])
= (.) (:) :: (a -> d) -> a -> [d] -> [d]
```

Answer (score 0):

`(.)` is nothing to fear. It is a most natural thing.

Imagine you define an *abstract* class of "connections":

```hs
class Connecting conn where
    plug :: conn a b -> conn b c -> conn a c
    noop :: conn a a
```

`conn a b` is a type of *something* which is connecting a *point* *a* to a *point* *b*.  Given the possibility of connecting *a* to *b*, and *b* to *c*, it most naturally gives us the possibility of connecting *a* to *c* by just plugging the two *somethings* together. Also, any *point* which can be connected to another, and can get connected to, can obviously be considered connected to itself with absolutely no effort.

*Functions* are connecting. Just use the output of one as the input of another. If we have such two compatible functions, plugging them in that way gives us a combined connection.

Functions [are](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/src/Control.Category.html#line-55) `Connecting`:

```hs
instance Connecting (->) where
    -- plug :: (->) a b -> (->) b c -> (->) a c
    (plug f g) x = g (f x)
    -- noop :: (->) a a
    noop x = x           -- what else? seriously. All we have is x.
```

Interesting thing about that `plug :: (->) a b -> (->) b c -> (->) a c`. That order of arguments is most fitting when we think about the types involved. But looking at its definition, we'd prefer it be defined as

```hs
    gulp :: (->) b c -> (->) a b -> (->) a c
    (gulp g f) x = g (f x)
```

Now the definition makes most sense, but the type feels a bit tortured.

Never mind that, we can have [both](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/src/Control.Category.html#%3C%3C%3C):

```hs
   (f :: a -> b)    >>>     (g :: b -> c)       ::    -- ...
         a          ->                 c

   (g :: b -> c)    <<<     (f :: a -> b)       ::    -- ...
                                  a ->
              c
```

Coincidentally, `<<<` is also known as `(.)`.

It is also clear that we have `(.) = (<<<) = flip (>>>)`, so `(g . f) x = g (f x) = (f >>> g) x`.

Presented with `g . f`, it is often easier to deal with the equivalent expression `f >>> g`, types-wise. Just align the types, vertically,

```hs
(:)        ::        b -> ([b] -> [b])
f          ::   a -> b
f >>> (:)  ::   a ->      ([b] -> [b])
```

so that

```hs
 (>>> (:)) ::  (a -> b)                      -- = ((:) <<<) = ((:) .) = (.) (:)
             -> a ->      ([b] -> [b])
```

[because](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139969/currying-3-arguments-in-haskell/13147064#13147064) `(>>> (:)) = (\f -> (f >>> (:)))`.

Which is `(\f -> ((:) <<< f)) = (\f -> ((:) . f)) = ((:) .) = (.) (:)`.

---

*edit:* for instance, the type of `(Endo . (:)) = ((:) >>> Endo)` is easily arrived at, with:

```hs
Endo         ::      ( b  ->  b ) -> Endo  b         
(:)          :: a -> ([a] -> [a])                    -- b ~ [a]
(:) >>> Endo :: a ->                 Endo [a]
```

For more about [`Endo`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/src/Data.Semigroup.Internal.html#Endo), try both `:t Endo` and `:i Endo` at GHCi prompt, and read up on [Haskell's record syntax](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/More_on_datatypes#Named_Fields_(Record_Syntax)), if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Writing `(.) (:)` as an operator section, `((:) .)`, emphasises a bit that it postcomposes `(:)` with some other function (i.e. it modifies a function by applying `(:)` to its result -- `\g -> (g .)` is `fmap` for functions). Symmetrically, `(. (:))` precomposes `(:)` with some other function (`\f -> (. f)` is `contramap` for functions -- cf. [the `Op` newtype](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-1.4.1/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html#t:Op)).